# Java. Начало карьеры.

Tags: работа, java

Хочу начать карьеру Java2EE разработчика. Опыта в этой области нет. Собственно вопросы:
Стоит ли пытаться делать что-то "для себя", потренироваться использовать популярные технологии (даст ли это что-то?) или лучше сразу идти искать где меня такого возьмут, пусть даже не в очень перспективной компании?
Представляя себя в роли работодателя, меня могут взять: а) "на вырост"; б) делать какие-то мелкие задачи/исправления. По каким признакам можно отличить первое от второго? Интеграторы и консалтинг — гиблое дело?

Comment: такого вас тоже возьмут. но знание "лишних" технологий "лишним" не бывает :)

Comment: Меня почему то улыбнула тема :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ну, карьера `Java2EE` разработчика, по моему, довольно перспективна. А еще более перспективна `Java` для `Andriod` (потому что больше платят и больше вакансий).
По-моему, для начала надо изучить азы. Если есть усидчивость, то флаг в руки и самоучитель перед глазами. Если маловато усидчивости, то прям сразу начинать программки писать, когда рядом учебник и интернет. Вот только опыта-то больше появляется от реальных проектов. Так что можно посоветовать изучить основы языка и пытаться найти работу. Пусть не высокооплачиваемую, но там можно уже на реальной практике обучиться.
Но и самое главное, что надо знать разработчику, так это `ПАТТЕРНЫ ПРОЕКТИРОВАНИЯ`. [Вот](http://oz.by/books/more10182766.html) прекрасная книга.

По поводу технологий, сразу много не изучишь, так что для начала основы языка. 
По поводу самых распространенных, так я думаю, что это `EJB`, `JPA`, `Hibernate`, `Spring`.

Comment: J2EE на мой взгляд будет всегда перспективней чем программирование под Andriod. Паттерны - далеко не главное...
Я бы посоветовал изучить базовое API, принять решение в каком направдении хотите двигаться в Java. После этого погуглить на тему "вопросы на собеседовании Java Junior" (есть отдельный топик на www.javatalks.ru). Изучить материалы согласно вопросам и пробываться на Java Junior.

Answer (score 3):

1. В первую голову надо как отче наш
       знать JSP/Servlet - это как
       говорится основы. Плюсом это тащит 
       еще легкие фрейворки навроде Struts
2. Далее надо знать тяжелые фреймворки. 
       Изучите модный ныне Spring, обращая
       особое внимание на JPA/Hibernate.
3. Забудьте про EJB - технология
       мертвая. Ну знать чуток надо, но не
       более того.